# Wrap text without CRLF in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, word-wrap

I have a very long text line (160000 characters). Is possible to view it in 1600 characters lines?

I need to view it in lines without inserting CR, LF or CRLF at the end of every line (TextFX - TextFX Edit - ReWrap inserts this characters).

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser... on which OS are you working? CAn you be more clear about which operation you would like to perform (maybe there is another tool to do it...). You can [edit] your own question to add this or other information.

Comment: No, not without inserting linke break characters or without limiting line length to width of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by enabling `Word wrap` (View -> Word Wrap), and scaling the width of your Notepad++ window to be 1600 characters wide.